# Get Full path of File which has this String in the name

Tags: c#

I got all the ID in a .txt files, my program read the file and store all the ID in a table of String.

What I want to do now, is get the full Path of the files containing the ID in the name and then move it in an other Directory.

I've tried this way and many other things, but doesn't seem to be working.

```
Console.WriteLine("" + lines[i]);
string fullPath = "Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Script\tiptop\");
Console.WriteLine("" + fullPath.Contains(lines[i]));"

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string ID = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Script\zig.txt");
    Console.WriteLine(ID);
    Console.ReadLine();
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Script\zig.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i <= lines.Length;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("" + lines[i]);
        string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Script\tiptop\");
        Console.WriteLine("" + fullPath.Contains(lines[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if you don't know in which directory the file/s is/are located, i am afraid you have to recursively search through all directories of interest for a file that has a matching name. One (or multiple) calls of the method `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(String, String, SearchOption)` will basically do it if you provide the correct argument values (for more details, read its documentation)

Comment: I know where the file are stored, it's in the tiptop folder :)

Comment: To make sure i understand you correctly: You just want to combine the path string of the tiptop folder with the file name (or relative file path) strings to produce the full file path string? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: exp_vente_ent_BP011910496.top                                             exp_vente_ent_BP011910496.tip                                                 I got the ID which are the 11 char ID, I need to get the full Path of the files containing the ID in their name. All the ID are actually stored in the String []

Comment: edited sorry, i've entered without finishing to type my comment  @elgonzo

Comment: Ah, okay. You would still use `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(String, String, SearchOption)` to enumerate files matching a certain search pattern (file name mask). The search pattern string you would build from the given ID value. Since you know the directory to search in, you could also use the `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(String, String)` overload

Comment: Oh, one more thing. I totally overlooked that you also want to move the found files. Thus it is probably better to use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles` instead of `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles`...

Answer (score 1):

Are the files all in the tiptop level directory?  OR are they a subdirectories under tiptop?

if top-level, does this help;

```
String root = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Script\tiptop\";

String[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Script\zig.txt");

for (int i = 0; i <= lines.Length; i++)
{
    string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, lines[i]);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath)) {
        // Do something...
    }

}
```